# jquery ajax return full page content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ubuntu

at the first , excuse me for my bad english

i working in ubuntu for a jquery/ajax system

my codes in below:

index.html

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="stuSelForm" id="stuSelForm">
<table id="inputTable">
<tr><td colspan="3" align="center">Stu From</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>St No : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="StNo" id="StNo" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>name : <br/> family : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="Fname" id="Fname" /><br/><input type="text" name="Lname" id="Lname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="right"><input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="show" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jscodes.js"></script>
...
```

js file :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#stuSelForm').submit(function(event)
{
    var form = $(this);
    inputs = form.find("input");
    serializedData = form.serialize();

    inputs.attr("disabled","disabled");

    $.ajax({
        url:'process.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: serializedData,
        dataType:'text',
        cache: false,
        success : function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){ alert(data); },
        error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) { alert(textStatus+jqXHR.status+jqXHR.responseText+"..."); },
        complete : function(jqXHR,textStatus)
                        {
inputs.removeattr("disabled");
                        }
        });
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

and process.php :

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html");
$StNo = $_POST['StNo'];
echo $_POST['StNo'];
?>
```

now all things are ok but the return value isn't StNo
it is whole content of process.php
it's mean

please help me why this happen
are this for php extensions or a mistake from me or ...

tanx for ur help

Comment: Take a look at [troubleshooting for PHP with Apache on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Checking_PHP_5_installation).

Comment: You mean the script is not evaluated?

Comment: do you have more content in **process.php** or just the one you are echoing as you mentioned above.

Comment: For asking clarification about your question don't use answering area. Try to ask via comment

Comment: no , just echo this post value , i test a fix value such az "1" but error still exist

Comment: tanx all , my problem was fixed . my mistake was in my url , url must be start with http:// that apache handle it but my url started with file:/// . tanx all

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the php is not running.  Are you running your HTML file which calls the php file through localhost / a server or directly from the directory? You need the php server to evaluate your php script.

Comment: Since you don't have a definite answer to provide, this would be more appropriate for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

problem in your header:
you write in jquery `dataType: text` but you write in php `header("Content-Type: text/html");`
change it for get success:
like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'process.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: serializedData,
    cache: false,
    success : function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){ alert(data); },
    error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) { alert(textStatus+jqXHR.status+jqXHR.responseText+"..."); },
    complete : function(jqXHR,textStatus){inputs.removeattr("disabled");}
    });
```

I remove `dataType:`, because jquery default settings is `dataType:'html'`
and you don't need write `dataType` in this case

Comment: i test html and text for dataType but not happen anything and now i remove this and any thing not change